# A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.ts(2371)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js

I am new to typescript and am using it only for React Bricks. I am trying to render a 3d object using threeJS and am getting the error mentioned above. I have tried passing colorMap as an argument in the function and declaring it outside the function scope but it still gives me an error.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useLoader } from "react-three-fiber";
import { TextureLoader } from "three/src/Three";
import logo from "../react-bricks/bricks/images/logo.jpg"


const Box: React.FC = (colorMap) => (
  const colorMap=useLoader(TextureLoader,logo.src);
  
   
    
    <mesh rotation={[90,0,20]}>
        <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[3,3,3]}/>
        <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap}/>
    </mesh>
  )

export default Box;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a *statement* (`const color = ___`) where an *expression* is required (within `()`). You're using the concise form of an arrow function, where you haven't used `{` as the first character after `=>` and so the entire function body must be an expression.

Instead, use the full form (with `{}`):

```
const Box: React.FC = (props) => { // <== {
    const colorMap = useLoader(TextureLoader, logo.src);

    return ( // <== return
        <mesh rotation={[90, 0, 20]}>
            <boxBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[3, 3, 3]} />
            <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMap} />
        </mesh>
    );
}; // <== }
```

Notice I changed `colorMap` in the parameter list to `props`, since you were declaring a local `const` with the name `colorMap`. Remember that function components receive an object as their first parameter value. That object has properties for the props provided to the component. So for instance, `<Box x={1} />` would receive an object with an `x` property with the value `1`. Usually (but not always!) people use destructuring to extract those properties from the object the function receives.

**If** `logo` is a prop, for instance, you might do:

```
const Box: React.FC<ThePropsObjectType> = ({logo}) => {
```

...where `ThePropsObjectType` is an object type defining the set of props of `Box` (with a `logo` prop).

Comment: Also side-error `const colorMap` will clash with the parameter and lead to a syntax error.

Comment: @VLAZ - LOL, I spotted the *other* side issue, but completely missed *that* one! :-)

Comment: It's 3D - has many sides :D